# jQuery/Javascript: Setting value of input is reset after focus change

Tags: javascript, jquery, flutter, webview2

I'm using an embedded Chromium version (Microsoft `WebView2`) in my Flutter-Desktop-App (Windows).

My goal is to use a `virtual keyboard` that is used "outside" of the embedded webview.

After a keystroke on my `virtual keyboard`, the corresponding `input` (text/email etc) should change its value accordingly.

I've tried the following:

1. Inject jQuery after page is loaded
2. Run Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dom = null;

  $("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]").click(function(e) {
    dom = this;
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

3. Page is loaded, user taps on an `input` (text, email, password)
4. Right after the user taps on the embedded `webview`, a script runs and returns: `"\$(dom).val()",`, this gets injected in the `TextController` outside the webview in order to type in more text.
5. Whenever a `virtual key` is pressed, this code runs:

```js
// $val is the value that was injected from my virtual keyboard
$(dom).val("$val").trigger("change");
```

6. What I've noticed is that the focus is lost, but the input is put in anyway (at least for `some sites`).

### The problem ❌

The problem is that this method only works on "some" sites:

- github.com
- stackoverflow.com
- duckduckgo.com

But it does not work here:

- https://app.splitser.com/
- Google/YouTube Login
- many more

`Splitser`: Whenever I type on my virtual keyboard, the value is set initially, but whenever I tap somewhere else, the input is **suddenly gone**. Why is that?
`Google`: Nothing is even applied in the first place.

What's going on? I'm having a hard time to just implement a virtual keyboard for my webview in an embedded system. Is it possible to access any TextControl directly?

PS: I'm embedding this in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual keyboard to input text into the input field, the change event may not be triggered by default. This is because virtual keyboards may not fire the necessary events to let the browser know that the value of the input field has changed.

To work around this, you can listen for an input event, which is fired whenever the value of the input field changes, even if it is changed programmatically or by a virtual keyboard.

Also, change event from click to change or on Change if using `trigger("change")`, for eg.

```
  $("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]").change(function(e) {})
  $("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]").on("input change", function(e) {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I think this goes to another direction. With the `click`-listener I get the `dom-element` that is later used with the injected script, because I cannot access it in any other way and bubble it up to the host-window (at least I do not know how).
I will try to add these functions, maybe the change will be registered.

Comment: Does it mean the "input" event is also not working while using the virtual keyboard?